# Polymer Paper dropdown selected value change selected value on ajax call

Tags: polymer

I have a paper dropdown menu polymer web component whose value changes on ajax call, the problem is that  i have set the selected property to 0, so when the listserial changes on ajax call i am still seeing the pervious first value of listserials, i tried attr-for-selected so that i select the first serial from listserials, but it doesn't show any selected  serial on ajax call

```
 <paper-dropdown-menu id="accountTypeDropdown" on-iron-
select="_itemSelected">
 <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected=0>
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{listSerials}}">
    <paper-item>{{item.serialno}}</paper-item>
   </template>
 </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the code that loads `listSerials` from the AJAX call.